# Unable to get the Document list from mongodb server in Android

Tags: android, json, mongodb, gson, httpresponse

i am using mongodb as cloud server for my android app.Mongodb java library doesn't work in Android so i am using rest api .i wrote the following code to get the json response and cast them into MyClass but its giving IllegalStateException with

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_Object at line 1 column 35
```

Code :

```
              try {  HttpGet mRequest = new HttpGet("https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/mydb/collections/mycol?apiKey=myKey");    

                     DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
   try {
              HttpResponse response = client.execute(mRequest);

              InputStream source = response.getEntity().getContent();

              Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(source);

              Gson gson = new Gson();

          Type typeOfCollectionOfMyObject = new TypeToken<Collection<MYObject>>(){}.getType();

          quizDBObjectList = gson.fromJson(reader, typeOfCollectionOfMyObject);

          } catch (IOException e) {
          mRequest.abort();
          }
```

this is not the whole code but i am getting the exception in this block.Any Help ?

Definition of MYObject is

```
           public class MYObject { 

                   private long index ;
                   private String question;
                   private String answer;
                   private String optionA;
                   private String optionB;
                   private String optionC;
                   private String optionD;
                   private String createdAt;
                   private String active;
                //getters and setters of data members
      }
```

and the response i got was :

```
                           [ { "_id" : { "$oid" : "505ab996aded66f4c1ccc7f2"} , "index" : 0 , "question" : "some text ?" , "optiona" : "optionA" , "optionb" : "optionB" , "optionc" : "OptionC" , "optiond" : "optionD" , "answer" : "answer" , "created_at" : { "$date" : "2012-09-20T06:37:04.306Z"} , "Active" : "1"} , { "_id" : { "$oid" : "505ab997aded66f4c1ccc7f3"} , "index" : 1 , ..../objects like that]
```

clearly i was not aware of the fact that the _id would be responded by the server.
Can you give me the correct class definition to cast this json object into my customized class. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_Object at line 1 column 35

This says it all, there should be somewhere `[` instead of `{`. Maybe you get a single object instead of an array?

The above might help or not. In order to get a better answer the following is needed:

- definition of `MYObject`
- the exact parsed String

You can get the parsed String e.g. by reading from `reader` into a `StringBuider` or simpler by using Guava's `CharStreams.toString(reader)`.

Comment: Thanks @maaartinus , i have edited my question , now it should give u the clear picture.

Comment: I can't see the problem, maybe except for confusing `typeOfCollectionOfQuizDBObject` and `typeOfCollectionOfMyObject`, but that probably happened while writing the question. With your object as given above, the only place where `BEGIN_ARRAY` is expected is the very beginning, and this is satisfied.

Comment: both are the same variables , i just made the correction. And you mean that the MYObject is correct enough to get the json objects ? i e keys of the json objects are correctly mapped with the data members of the my custom class.

Comment: Actually not, e.g., there's `"optiona" : "optionA"`, but there's no property named `optiona` (with a small "a"). But this again might be a type made here and more important: This can't cause the error reported. There must be some array somewhere as it's expected. Try to simplify in order to localize the problem: Remove step-wise everything until the problem goes away. As unmapped properties get simply ignored, it should be very easy.

Comment: thanks for pointing out, with some changes in the code i am able to get pass this error but i am getting another exception as i am trying to get the data from the MYObject and put it into the sqlite.I will make the changes and see if this works.